# I can't solve a problem relating subqueries

Tags: sql, subquery

So here is the task: Find the continents where all countries have a population <= 25000000. Then find the names of the countries associated with these continents. Show name, continent and population.

My take on it:

```
select continent, name, population
from world x
where name = all(select name from world y
where y.continent=x.continent
and population<2500000 and population>0)
```

It doesn't bring me desired results, it only gives me two countries from Eurasia.

Comment: Please tag appropriate database name, some sample data with your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select name, continent, population 
from world t
where not exists (
   select 1 from world 
   where continent = t.continent and population > 25000000
);
```

or with a subquery to use with the `IN` operator:

```
select name, continent, population 
from world
where continent in (
   select continent from world
   group by continent 
   having max(population) <= 25000000
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a join to combine the two tables--rather than a subquery? That might help as well? Also I don't quite understand "world x" vs. your other table "y,", so you might need to adjust my query a bit. Hope this helps!!

```
SELECT continent, name, population
from world x
JOIN y on y.continent = x.continent
WHERE population < 2500000 and population > 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Is that a requirement of using sub query? Your query basically equivalent to-

```
SELECT continent, name, population
FROM world x
WHERE population > 0 
AND population < 2500000
```